# How can I simplify this pieces of repeated codes?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a component which has many events, and I want to control this events by one flag. As readOnly becomes true, all events should not work. Here's an example.

```html
<div>
  <div onclick="event1" />
  <div onclick="event2" />
  <div onclick="event3" />
</div>
```

```js
const event1 = () => {
    if (!readOnly) {
        // do something
    }
}

const event2 = () => {
    if (!readOnly) {
        // do something
    }
}

const event3 = () => {
    if (!readOnly) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

There are repeated codes in every events, and I want to simplify this.
Is there an idea to simplify this codes?

I thought the template method pattern first, but I don't use it because it has too much overhead as I think. Also, there is a solution like this code below.

```html
<div>
  <div onclick="doWhenNotReadOnly(event1)" />
  <div onclick="doWhenNotReadOnly(event2)" />
  <div onclick="doWhenNotReadOnly(event3)" />
</div>
```

```js
const doWhenNotReadOnly = (function) => {
    if (readOnly) return;
    function();
}

const event1 = () => {
    // do something
}

const event2 = () => {
    // do something
}

const event3 = () => {
    // do something
}
```

Are this codes are better than first codes?

Comment: you can create a function with args. `const event(x) => do something on x`

Comment: I would use `if (readOnly) return; // do something` to reduce nesting.

Comment: How do you *set* readOnly?  You could add `pointer-events:none` to the relevant `div`s then they wont generate click events in the first place.

Comment: A component gets readOnly value while it is loaded. So, I thought a template method pattern first to execute each events. But, I thought it has too many overheads because it only checks readOnly value in parent class.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "component".   Sounds like you could use js events rather than onclick, then simply not add the event if it's readonly.

Comment: That can be one solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var readOnly = false;
function execAnEvent(evt){
  switch(evt){
    case 1:
      document.write("<p>This is random number: " + Math.random() + "<p>");
      break;
    case 2:
      alert("You have clicked me!");
      break;
    case 3:
      if(confirm("Wanna open https://majorflux.codehs.me?")){
        window.open("https://majorflux.codehs.me");
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      console.error("255.255.255.255.255.255 is an invalid IP address!");
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
div{
  background: red;
  border: 2px outset green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="execAnEvent(1);"></div>
<div onclick="execAnEvent(2);"></div>
<div onclick="execAnEvent(3);"></div>
<div onclick="execAnEvent(4);"></div>
```

Usage of a switch element can help, in combination with a function that has at least one parameter.